# Issues with XML references

Tags: c#, xml

I am making a web browser and once again, i am stuck. The code i am currently using creates an XML document and uses that document to save and reference Bookmarks and Favourites. Here is the code:

```
public static String favXml = "favourites.xml", linksXml = "links.xml";
String settingsXml = "settings.xml", historyXml = "history.xml";
List<String> urls = new List<String>();
XmlDocument settings = new XmlDocument();
String homePage;
CultureInfo currentCulture;
```

and then references it with this code:

```
private void addFavourite(String url, string name)
{
    XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement el = myXml.CreateElement("favorit");
    el.SetAttribute("url", url);
    el.InnerText = name;
    if (!File.Exists(favXml))
    {
        XmlElement root = myXml.CreateElement("favourites");
        myXml.AppendChild(root);
        root.AppendChild(el);
    }
    else
    {
        myXml.Load(favXml);
        myXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(el);
    }

    myXml.Save(favXml);
}
```

This issue i have with that code, is that every time i publish an update - it resets the users' bookmarks. I really don't know how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated and anyone who can help will be mentioned in my changelogs and at final release. I currently have 36 preview testers and they are all annoyed by this glitch.

Comment: What do you mean by 'publish an update'? How do you publish an update, do you ship a new installer, do you have an update service? My guess would be; your update/install mechanism is deleting or overwriting the `favourites.xml` file. Also try adding some logging into the `addFavourite` method, so you can see what is happening.

Comment: Did you debug your own code?

Answer (score 0):

The code logic doesn't have problem, I advise refactor the condition sentence.

```
if (!File.Exists(favXml))
```

Initialize the  .xml file when the app starts up, including generate the root element. then `private void addFavourite(String url, string name)` only add element to this xml.

And if you use this file in multithread, you'd better lock the file to avoid overwrite.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should load required XML file to your `XmlDocument` so that you will get updated XML result.

```
private void addFavourite(String url, string name)
{
   XmlDocument myXml = new XmlDocument();       
   if (File.Exists(favXml))
   {         
      myXml.Load(favXml); // load your XML file here          
   }
   else
   {
      XmlElement root = myXml.CreateElement("favourites");
      myXml.AppendChild(root);
   }

    XmlElement el = myXml.CreateElement("favorit");
    el.SetAttribute("url", url);
    el.InnerText = name;
    myXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(el);
    myXml.Save(favXml); 
}
```

Note: To test this method you should handle file creation and deletion logic over testing framework's setup() and tearDown() process
--SJ

Comment: At that point in the code, it's been checked the file doesn't exist - so what do you propose is loaded?

Comment: @CharlesMager, thanks for pointing out my mistake, now i updated my solution!